# Integrating python-decouple with PRAW?

Tags: python-3.x, praw, decoupling, python-decouple

I've been trying to see if I can use python-decouple to place my bot credentials on a separate .env file.

Auth method is basically right off the praw doc:

```
    reddit = praw.Reddit(
        client_id=config('CLIENT_ID'),
        client_secret=config('CLIENT_SECRET'),
        password=config('PASSWORD'),
        user_agent=config('USER_AGENT'),        
        username=config('USERNAME')
    )
```

However, whenever I try it, it seems to return an 403 auth error. I work my way back, replacing the decouple configs with strings of the actual details, but it doesn't seem to follow through, and the errors that occur seem random depending on what and when things I take out.

Is this a problem with how decouple functions?

Thanks.

Comment: Were you trying in the window when Reddit was returning errors:  https://reddit.statuspage.io/

Comment: Nope, this was a while ago when Reddit was up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've been trying to see if I can use python-decouple to place my bot credentials on a separate .env file.

Why not use a `praw.ini` file? This is documented [here](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/configuration/prawini.html#defining-additional-sites) in PRAW documentation. It's a format for storing Reddit credentials in a separate file from your code. For example, a `praw.ini` file may look like:

```
[bot1]
client_id=Y4PJOclpDQy3xZ
client_secret=UkGLTe6oqsMk5nHCJTHLrwgvHpr
password=pni9ubeht4wd50gk
username=fakebot1

[bot2]
client_id=6abrJJdcIqbclb
client_secret=Kcn6Bj8CClyu4FjVO77MYlTynfj
password=mi1ky2qzpiq8s59j
username=fakebot2
```

You then use specific credentials in your code like so:

```
import praw

reddit = praw.Reddit('bot2', user_agent='myBot v0.1')
print('Logged in as', reddit.user.me())
```

I think this is the best solution for working with PRAW credentials.

---

However, if you really want to do it with `python-decouple`, here's a working example:

*Contents of file `.env`*:

```
username=k8IA
password=REDACTED
client_id=REDACTED
client_secret=REDACTED
```

*Contents of file `connect.py`*:

```
import praw

from decouple import config

reddit = praw.Reddit(username=config('username'),
        password=config('password'),
        client_id=config('client_id'),
        client_secret=config('client_secret'),
        user_agent='myBot v0.1')

print('Logged in as', reddit.user.me())
```

*Output when running `python3 connect.py`*:

```
Logged in as k8IA
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although I was more curious to how decouple treated the variables in a way that made it not work even though the readme mentions how they should return as strings, and so my curiosity.

Comment: @MatStornel I was not able to reproduce any way in which python-decouple did *not* work with PRAW, so I cannot answer your question regarding that. Can you provide an example in which it doesn't work?

Comment: An OAuthExeception for invalid_grant seems to occur when I config the username. I suspect it has to do with the fact that the username includes a dash and/or underscore, because the auth seems to accept the user_agent variable with spaces, and the rest.

Comment: @MatStornel That sounds to me like something about your specific credentials. If, for example, your password is `Hello_there-world!`, try `print(config('password') == 'Hello_there-world!')` to see whether python-decouple is properly storing your password.